# Cenetral Horizontal alignment of cell design webpage

Tags: css, center-align

I have a webpage I made awhile ago, When coding I was not thinking of responsiveness and making it responsive is proving an issue.

When the window is in the original width (currently set as the min-width) the page looks like this:
[image]

When the window is between 960px and 1380px (my max width) I get a strange mid-way white border on the right hand side of the page:
[image]

And when the window is at or above 1380px the page looks like this:
[image]

*Please note, you may need to open the image location to see the border on the white stackoverflow background!*

I have tried lots of things, such as changing the float for a margin-left margin-right align, and changing floats of alternating cells, but I can't get anything to work. I need the cells to become equally spaced while the page is being re-sized.

Here is my css for the list items currently;

```
#server_features li{
    width:414px;
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    float:left;
    border-width:3px;
    border-style:solid;
}
```

If you need anymore information, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Please post a complete code example, including your HTML.

Comment: Added fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uyxfnnb2/ The text scaling is not particularly perfect, but the box sizes should be good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working example [jsfiddle update example](http://jsfiddle.net/uyxfnnb2/2/)
First: set for ul

```
overflow: hidden;
```

and remove

```
position absolute;
```

Next remove your max and min widt and use media queries
In media queries set your ul width (margin-left + margin-right + bodrer-left + border-right + padding-left + padding-right + width) in your example width for one column is 460px for 2 colums is 920px for 3 columns is 1380px etc.
I used youe example and I change that what I wrote above so you can see how it's works.

Comment: no problem remove this style from #welcome
min-width:960px;
max-width:1380px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
You don't will be need this when you set overflow hidden for ul #server_features you will see

Comment: This worked well, I had to tweak a few numbers as my outline wrapper was 90% (not 100%). Other than that, perfect!